# Understanding segfault with static size array of std::tuple in class

Tags: arrays, c++11, stdtuple

I have a class that where I want to store three datapoints for each pixel in an image. I thought std::tuple would be a nice way to do this so:

```
class CameraManager {
private:
    static const int width_  = 700;
    static const int height_ = 574;
     //this causes a segfault...
    std::tuple<double,double,bool> mapping_[width_][height_];

public:
    CameraManager();

}
```

The segfault happens directly at main(int argc, char ** argv) because I have a camera manager object declared in this function.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're putting something like 6MB on your call stack with that. It's really at the sort of size where you want to avoid automatic storage duration.

Try allocating it dynamically.

Comment: Makes sense. Just curious, what would happen if I defined the array as a global variable in e.g. the file where main.cpp is defined. Where would the memory be allocated, text part of the program?

Answer (score 1):

Let's make some calculations: an `std::tuple<double,double,bool>` costs roughly 24 bytes on [some machines](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5b409325e0eb2a0c) and therefore a matrix 700x574 will cost about 9'643'200 bytes, which is ~10MB.

Most implementations allocate 1MB, maybe 2MB of stack size. If your implementation allows you to specify a bigger stack size, then set that to something greater than ~12MB.

Otherwise allocate `mapping_` dynamically:

```
using my_tuple = std::tuple<double,double,bool>;
std::vector<my_tuple> mapping_;
```

and then:

```
CameraManager() : mapping_(width_ * height_) { ... }
```

and maybe create a simple matrix view over that `vector`.